# Filter With Multiple Values

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

In Magento 2.4.1 I have a custom multiple select attribute 'theme'
The theme attribute contains options 'football' and 'sport'
Some products have both attribute options applied. I can apply both attribute values to a product fine but when I filter in product grid dashboard, it does not find products which have more than one attribute value applied.
If a product has one attribute value only then it filters correctly but if a product has multiple attribute filters applied it does not show.
Is this a default Magento 2 setting?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did take a look at this question. A multiselect attribute gets stored in a table with `varchar` suffix. For instance, product attribute `activity` (present in Magento sample data) is stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. Also, the value is a list of options ids.

see attached[image] screenshot.

Therefore, your query has to use a like filter, see below an example.

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\MultiSelectFilter\Command;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GetProductWithSeveralMultiselectOptions extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * GetProductWithSeveralMultiselectOptions constructor.
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param string|null $name
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        string $name = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('mbs:find:product');
        $this->setDescription('Find Product in catalog focusing with multiselect attribute');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('activity')
            ->setConditionType('like')
            ->setValue('%5432%')
            ->create();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filter])->create();

        $result = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        foreach ($result->getItems() as $product) {
            $output->writeln(sprintf('sku: %s', $product->getSku()));
        }

        $output->writeln('CFart log import complete');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I'm fairly new to Magento, how would I use this and where?

Comment: This is a command-line script showing you how to build a query with a multiselect attribute. I read that is what you needed. Good luck with Magento